# Aurelia Validation - Validating multiple checkboxes or radios

Tags: javascript, validation, aurelia

I am trying to validate that at least 1 checkbox was selected using the Aurelia validator.  I was assuming that using the minItems() method would be sufficient but it seems I can only make this work by a 'hack' using a hidden element pointing to my array.  Does anyone know of a more simple approach to handling this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with groups of radios or checkboxes it's easiest to put the validation on the group instead of each individual input element. This approach requires building a custom element for "checkbox-group" and/or "radio-group". Here's an example of a checkbox group with validation:

[checkboxes component that is compatible with validation](https://gist.run/?id=7374d1b8c00dc9b89efda3f059f59083)

```html
<label id="color1">
  Colors 1:
  <checkbox-select items-source.bind="colors"
                   value.bind="colors1 & validate"
                   aria-labelledby="color1">
  </checkbox-select>
</label>
```

[radio group component that is compatible with validation](https://gist.run/?id=a78d15898660218b8438e34dcc31f390)

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy.  I was planning on taking this approach if there was no other way.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: What about pass the validator and validate inside valueChanged?